# Question about kernels and cokernels ...

Tags: abstract-algebra, homological-algebra

Let $\mathcal{C}$ be an abelian category. Let $f:A\rightarrow B$ be a morphism. Let $c=\text{coker(ker f)}:A\rightarrow C$ (the coimage of $f$). Prove that there is a unique map $i:C\rightarrow B$ such that $f:i\circ c$, and prove that $i=\text{ker(coker f)}$.

I have been able to prove everything except the last part $i=\text{ker(coker f)}$. From what I know, it is $\text{ker(coker f)}=\text{ker(coker(}i\circ c))=\text{ker(coker i)}=i$ since $c$ is epic. Thus $i=\text{ker(coker f)}$.

I understood the above equality except

$\text{ker(coker(}i\circ c))=\text{ker(coker i)}$ which I don't know how to prove and is the crux of the problem. How does $c$ being epic makes the equality true?

The other equalities make sense. Any help appreciated.

Comment: You are using $C$ to denote two things.

Comment: Thanks for the link; apparently it answers the question but its explanation is not easy to understand.

Comment: I changed the notation for $C$ to $\mathcal{C}$ as per Arturo's suggestion. Thanks for pointing that out.